# Setting up Eloquent relationships in Laravel for existing InnoDB relationships

Tags: migration, schema, relationship, laravel, eloquent

I have an initial migration that sets up two tables (users and projects), with a relationship (innoDB).

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

I have two Eloquent models set up, blank except for the relationship:

```
return $this->has_many('Project');
```

Do I *definitely* need to tell eloquent about the relationship in the models *and* the database? I'd assumed something as comprehensive as Laravel would infer it from the Schema? Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, you have to define the relationships in your Models.

Laravel doesn't analyze the schema, foreign key indexes are actually not mandatory to use.
This bootstraping may could be avoided, but it also allows you to use non-conventional table and column names or use the Fluent Query Builder to modify the relationship queries.

Less magic, more control for now.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. Odd though - Eloquent already allows you more control, such as overriding the default table for a model.